# Array inside a type in julia

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I'm trying to make a type with an array inside but having trouble to do it.

This is my code:

```
type Gradient
    color::GrandientPoint
    Gradient(color=[]) = new(color)
    function Gradient(rgb::RGB)
        push!(color,GrandientPoint(rgb,0))
    end
end
```

I'm getting this error

> ERROR: UndefVarError: color not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function Gradient(rgb::RGB)
    push!(color,GrandientPoint(rgb,0))
end
```

You never made `color` here, so you can't `push!` into `color` since it doesn't exist. In fact, you don't need to. To define a type, you just call `new` with the values for it:

```
function Gradient(rgb::RGB)
    new(GrandientPoint(rgb,0))
end
```

that makes a `Gradient` where the first field gets the value `GrandientPoint(rgb,0)`, and returns it.

---

If you wanted an array, then your type would be

```
type Gradient
    color::Vector{GrandientPoint}
end
```

not just a GraidentPoint. Now you can make that vector by using its constructor. Types have a sensible constructor from their type's name. So to make a `Vector{GrandientPoint}`, you just do

```
Vector{GraidentPoint}()
```

and you can push stuff into there. The full code with the constructor:

```
type Gradient
    color::Vector{GrandientPoint}
    Gradient(color=[]) = new(Vector{GradientPoint}())
    function Gradient(rgb::RGB)
        color = Vector{GradientPoint}()
        push!(color,GrandientPoint(rgb,0))
        new(color)
    end
end
```

Comment: But that makes an array? how can I add elements to it?

Comment: Note that @exsnake likely wants `Vector{GradientPoint}`, if I'm understanding correctly. (Hence the `new(color)` with `color[]`.)

Comment: Ahh, that makes the title make more sense. Yeah, there were no vectors in his/her original problem. I edited the answer to include the arrays in case that's what he/she wanted.

Comment: I don't get one thing. What is doing `new(color)`?

Comment: `new(color)` makes a new Gradient object where the first field holds the variable `color`. It doesn't have to be the same name though. If we did         `color2 = Vector{GradientPoint}(); push!(color,GrandientPoint(rgb,0))`, then `new(color2)` would make a new Graident where `.color` would be what we made as `color2`.